# WPF - How do I display a tooltip on "touch" screen over disabled tab?

Tags: wpf, xaml, tooltip

I am trying to figure out how to have a tool tip show up only when a tab is disabled, but on a mouse/touch event, as well as mouse hover.  Right now, I have it working to show the tool tip when I hover over the disabled tab on my desktop monitor. However, on my touch-screen device, touching the tab shows the tool-tip for about 20ms. This is because the mouse down event seems to clear the tool tip.   Here is what I have working so far:

```
<TabItem Name="BiosTab" IsEnabled="{Binding Path=EnableAllTabs}" 
                         Header="Peripherals/BIOS" Height="64" Style="{StaticResource GlowTabItem}"
                         ToolTip="{Binding Path=TabToolTip}" ToolTipService.ShowOnDisabled="True"
                         ToolTipService.InitialShowDelay="0" PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="BiosTab_MouseLeftButtonDown">
```

Quick background:
We have 3 tabs, each showing a list of files that can be installed by category.  There is a required category of files that must be installed before others from the other groups can be installed.   So, until those items are installed or selected for installation, the other tabs remain disabled.   To be user friendly, I want the tool tip to appear when a user tries to activate one of the disabled tabs.

Unfortunately, the PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown event does not get called while the tab is disabled, so that piece isn't helping.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to look for a WPF toast notifications library.

Meanwhile, a simple solution might be this:

- Leave the `TabItems` enabled and handle `CanExecute` behavior.
- Create new `TabItem` style based on the disabled style (you may want to
  distinguish between them though).
- Handle `ToolTip` opening and closing on button up* or mouse leave.

```cs
private Timer Timer { get; set; }
private ToolTip ToolTip { get; set; }

{
    ...
    Timer = new Timer();
    Timer.Interval = 3000;
    Timer.Elapsed += OnTimerElapsed;

    BiosTab.MouseLeave += OnMouseLeave;
    BiosTab.MouseLeftButtonUp += OnMouseButtonUp;
}

public void OnMouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    CloseToolTip();
}

public void OnMouseButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    Timer.Stop();
    ToolTip = ((ToolTip)((Control)sender).ToolTip);
    ToolTip.IsOpen = true;
    Timer.Start();
}

private void CloseToolTip()
{
    if (ToolTip != null)
    {
        ToolTip.IsOpen = false;
        ToolTip = null;
    }
}

private void OnTimerElapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    Timer.Stop();
    Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)CloseToolTip, DispatcherPriority.Send);
}
```

Comment: Thanks.   I do believe this is the only way.   I was really hoping for a way to bubble the event when the control is disabled.  But all searching has shown that there is no easy way (like the attribute for the "ShowOnDisabled" attribute for ToolTipService).   I appreciate your sample code.  I will be using it or something very similar to solve my problem.